# Square with different densities. Computing probability.

Tags: probability

[image: square with different densities]

I have a question about computing P(Y<0.5). Inside this square [-1,1] x [-1,1] we have different density function f(x,y). We can do it directly by counting area and it is 0.75. Because 4 is area of all square and 3 is done by 2*1.5. We can also use integral of density of x which is f(x). Although second option is more scientific it gives the same results. When i can use both options and when only this with integral ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking and what the square is supposed to represent.

Comment: I believe the OP is writing out the probability density quadrant by quadrant.  Upper right and upper left are both uniform.  At a point $(x,y)$ in the lower right, density is $\frac x2$, in the lower left it is $-\frac y2$.  This does indeed give total probability $1$.  Not sure about the question though.  The area calculation is the same as the integral.  We already know the probability (=integral) of $y≤0$ is $\frac 12$, we needed that to show this was a true probability density.  And the probability that $0≤y≤\frac 14$ is clearly half of the top probability, hence $\frac 14$.

Comment: The question seems reasonable but it might help to define $f(x, y)$. It is impossible to calculate $P(Y<0.5)$ without knowing how $Y$ is defined.

Comment: @SlugPue  Pretty sure OP meant $Y=y$.

Comment: OP here, you are completely right, X is defined from -1 to 1, same as y.

Comment: Ok, good.  But then I see no difference at all between the area calculation, and the integral.  The integral methodology is, of course, more general.  If you had asked for the probability that, say $y≥x^2-1$ then we would have to do it by an integral, as we (or at least, I) simply can't evaluate the "weighted area" geometrically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that the figure shows the density of $f(X,Y)$ with $Y$ in the
vertical axis (which coincides with the vertical line through the center
of the figure) and $X$ in the horizontal axis (which coincides with the
horizontal line through the center of the figure).

Technically, to evaluate $P(Y<0.5)$ you must perform an integration.
It is very easy to integrate the density in the upper half of the figure
(where $Y > 0$), however: just take $0.5$ times the area over which 
you are integrating.

The region where $Y<0.5$ is everything *except* a strip along the upper
edge of the figure consisting of the top half of each of the smaller squares
labeled $0.5$. The area of this region is $1$,
so you can easily find $P(Y \geq 0.5)$, and you can take
$P(Y<0.5) = 1 - P(Y \geq 0.5)$.

Alternatively, you could compute integrals over the two smaller
squares at the bottom of the figure. This would confirm that the total
weight of each of these squares is $0.25$.

If you had to compute $P(X<0.5)$ the calculation would be slightly more
difficult, because you would have to account for the fact that the
probability density is not uniform within the smaller square
on the lower right, and the weight of the left half of that square
does not equal the weight of the right half.
You might therefore have to do something that is more obviously 
an integration.